# 2%F in my link, using Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hyperlink, decode

i have a select with many products

For example

```
<select id="subscription">
  <option value="24072">Excel Intermedio</option>
  <option value="24071">Excel Avanzado</option>
  <option value="24074">Microsoft Project</option>
</select>
<div id="button"><a id="order-btn" href="http://page.com/?add-to-cart=24072">PAGAR</a></div></center>
```

and one button, change when u select one of them
page.com/?add-to-cart=24072, but if choose Microsoft Project, the value is change, i made with javascript

```
document.getElementById("subscription").onchange = function() {
    var value = this.value;
    var link = "http://page.com/?add-to-cart=";
    document.getElementById("order-btn").href = decodeURIComponent(link+value);
}
```

but when i push to pay in "PAGAR" button, the link throw me this:

```
https://page.com/?add-to-cart=24066%2F
```

What I can not understand is that 2% F that is added only to my link, I read something about decodeUriComponent, but it does not work for me, I must be doing something wrong, but I have been doing this for hours, if you can help me, I would appreciate it

Comment: Looks like `encodeURIComponent` is being used somewhere or your options look like `<option value="24074/">Microsoft Project</option>`, cant reproduce this as-is.

Comment: If it happens after clicking the link, it could be a poor .htaccess rule to always place a / at the end of the url.

Comment: Exactly, it happens when clicking, because when I place the mouse over the button to see the link that is generated in the bottom corner, it shows up fine, but when I click, it changes and throws me 2% F